# Fix PHP Fatal error Call to a member function result() on boolean

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

I am getting an error in my CodeIgniter project.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on boolean in /apps/config/routes.php on line 6
```

This is the code:

```
require_once( BASEPATH . 'database/DB.php' );
$db =& DB();
$result = $db->get( 'options' )->result();
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/examples.html#initializing-the-database-class

Comment: Could you explain what it is you are actually trying to do?

Comment: i am getting this error when trying to get result or or tryin to get options

Comment: @new php: `$db->get('options');` seems to be a boolean. You can not call a function on a boolean. That is why you get this error.

Comment: $result = $db->get( 'options' )->result();            this is the 6th line of routes.php

Comment: ok so how i can get options ?

Comment: Where are you planning to use them? It looks like you are attempting to create dynamic routes? Is that why this is in the routes.php file?

Comment: The return from $db->get(...)` is `FALSE`, and `result()` is not a method of the boolean FALSE. Booleans are not class objects. In short, the call to `get` is failing. Probably due to the way you are attempting to load the DB class.